# Unicode error on python 3 using winsound

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to get python to play a audio using winsound, but I keep getting an error and I'm pretty confused. Here's the code:

```
from winsound import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('C:\Users\David\Desktop\MP5_SMG.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

MP5_SMG.wav is the filename. It gives me the following error:

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' can't decode bytes in position
2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Also, when the error pops up, the first parentheses is highlighted in red.

I'm open to trying another way to play audio in python. If you have a solution or another please let me now. All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `\U` is the start of a Unicode character escape.

Comment: So instead of C it's U?

Comment: I'm talking about the `\U` start to `\Users`, which Python expects to be a `\Uhhhhhhhh` Unicode escape sequence, and `s` is not hex character like it expected. See the duplicate post, you need to escape your backslashes or use a raw string literal.